# When to draw (and hide) the underline for a owner draw menu bar

Tags: winapi, menu

In the post below

[Menu Accelerator Keys (underline) for Owner-Draw menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861937/menu-accelerator-keys-underline-for-owner-draw-menu-items)

I asked a question about "how to" draw the underline when users use `Alt` key to navigate the system menu, if the menubar is owner-draw. It is done (Thank `Hans Passant`).

But now comes another question: "When to" draw (and hide) the underline.

After the `Alt` is down, the `WM_DRAWITEM` messages are generated (for all items), then `WM_SYSCOMMAND with wParam == SC_KEYMENU`, and finally `WM_DRAWITEM` for the selected item.

See the message list at the end.

Since after WM_SYSCOMMAND, there is no WM_DRAWITEM for other items, I have to use `WM_SYSKEYDOWN with VK_MENU` to indicate that a user is using the key to navigate the system menu. So I got the following code: (Here `byKey` is a static bool variable)

```
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    {
        if (wParam == VK_MENU)
            byKey = true;
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    case WM_EXITMENULOOP:
    {
        if (wParam == 0)
            byKey = false;
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

My question is that: ***Is there a better way to know "When to" draw (and hide) the underline??***

```
<00686> 000B0444 P WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0 [wParam:00000012 lParam:20380001]
<00687> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00688> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00689> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00690> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00691> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00692> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00693> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00694> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00695> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00696> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00697> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00698> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00699> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00700> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00701> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EF080 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EF080]
<00702> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
....
<00708> 000B0444 P WM_SYSKEYUP nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1 [wParam:00000012 lParam:C0380001]
<00709> 000B0444 S WM_SYSCOMMAND uCmdType:SC_KEYMENU xPos:0 yPos:0 (used mnemonic) [wParam:0000F100 lParam:00000000]
<00710> 000B0444 S WM_ENTERMENULOOP fIsTrackPopupMenu:False [wParam:00000000 lParam:00000000]
<00711> 000B0444 R WM_ENTERMENULOOP lResult:00000000
....

<00714> 000B0444 S WM_INITMENU hmenuInit:01B10471 [wParam:01B10471 lParam:00000000]
<00715> 000B0444 R WM_INITMENU lResult:00000000
    <00716> 000B0444 S WM_DRAWITEM idCtl:0 lpdis:003EECE8 [wParam:00000000 lParam:003EECE8]
<00717> 000B0444 R WM_DRAWITEM fProcessed:True [lResult:00000001]
<00718> 000B0444 S WM_MENUSELECT uItem:0 fuFlags:MF_POPUP | MF_HILITE | MF_OWNERDRAW hmenu:01B10471 [wParam:01900000 lParam:01B10471]
<00719> 000B0444 R WM_MENUSELECT lResult:00000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `WM_DRAWITEM` message contains a pointer to a `DRAWITEMSTRUCT`. In that structure, the `ODS_NOACCEL` flag will be set in the `itemState` if the underline should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the message `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Its implementation may look like this:

```
DWORD dwUiState = 0;  // current control state, usually a member in per-control struct.

switch(uMsg) {
   case WM_UPDATEUISTATE:
      switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
         case UIS_INITIALIZE:  dwUiState = HIWORD(wParam); break;
         case UIS_CLEAR:       dwUiState &= ~HIWORD(wParam); break;
         case UIS_SET:         dwUiState |= HIWORD(wParam); break;
      }
      InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
      break;

   // ... handling of other messages
}
```

And in `WM_PAINT`, you should paint the underline when `!(dwUiState & UISF_HIDEACCEL)`.

Comment: @mityMy app never generate or receive WM_UPDATEUISTATE. Should I use SendMessage to generate this message? But if so, when I need to send this message?

Comment: System (since XP, AFAIK), sends it to the active (focused) top-level window, e.g. when `ALT` is pressed. The top-level window should pass it to `DefWindowProc()` which distributes to to its child windows.

Comment: Weired. No WM_UPDATEUISTATE, (I used break point in WM_UPDATEUISTATE).

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054036/show-hotkeys-at-all-times, David Heffernan said an application should use SendMessage to send WM_UPDATEUISTATE. But this doesn't help to my question.